# Split pandas dataframe stratified by one column but grouped by another

Tags: pandas, train-test-split

I have a pandas Dataframe with columns A,B and C.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


size = 30

column_a_values = np.random.randint(1, 4, size=size)
column_b_values = np.random.choice(['x', 'y', 'z'], size=size)
column_c_values = np.random.rand(size)


data = {'A': column_a_values, 'B': column_b_values, 'C': column_c_values}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head()
```

```
    A   B   C
0   2   y   0.351586
1   1   y   0.353851
2   2   x   0.404016
3   1   y   0.298571
4   1   x   0.018221
```

I want to split the rows into a train and a test set. My requirements are, that the split is stratified over column B, but **grouped by column A, meaning that no value of A must be both in train and test.** Depending on the split ratio, the current example data might not be fit for this purpose, but I'm able to drop some of the rows if needed.

Comment: Based on how I understand your requirements, test will either contain an entry form column A which is equal to 1 or 2 and Train will contain the other value.  Is this correct?  What do you mean by stratify over Column B?

Comment: I think these two condiftions are not compatible for A!=B. How about: you use all rows with A=1 for training and A=2 for testing (or vice versa). Then you use ratio of B values from test set to upsample or downsample training set.

Comment: agree, that the conditions may be incompatible. Marked as duplicate now